# uploading random images on an applet window in java

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, awt

I have been trying to upload an image onto a Java Applet Window but unfortunately it turns out to be blank..Here is the code i have written pls help!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RandomImages extends JFrame
{
  private Image img;

public void static main(String[] args)
{
  new RandomImages();
}

public RandomImages()
{
  super("Random Images");
  setSize(450,450);
  setVisible(true);
  setResizable(false);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  Toolkit tk=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
  img=tk.getImage(getURL("Your File Name"));
}
```

Below is the code that fetches the url of the filename looking for...

```
private URL getURL(String filename)
{
  URL url=null;
  try{
    url=this.getClass().getResource(filename);
  }
  catch(Exception e) {}
  return url;
}

AffineTransform id=new AffineTransform();
```

Code for paint component...

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
  super.paint(g);
  Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g;
  AffineTransform trans=new AffineTransform();
  Random rand=new Random();
  g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  width=getSize().width;
  height=getSize().height;
  g2d.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
```

Loop for generating random ships on screen

```
for(int s=0;s<20;s++)
{
  trans.setTransform(id);
  trans.translate(rand.nextInt()%width,rand.nextInt()%height);
  trans.rotate(Math.toRadians(360*rand.nextDouble()));
  double scaled=rand.nextDouble()+1;
  trans.scale(scaled,scaled);
  trans.drawImage(img,trans,this);
}
}

}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add image in `JFrame` is to use `JLabel`.

Example:

```
 JLabel image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Image.jpg"));
```

Now add this JLabel(image) into your JFrame.

```
public RandomImages()
{
  super("Random Images");
  setSize(450,450);
  setVisible(true);
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());//you have not used the Layout
  setResizable(false);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  JLabel image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Image.jpg"));
  add(image);
}
```

Another way is to use [drawImage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html) function of Graphics  class in `paint(Graphics g)`  function .
But you should use `paintComponent` against `paint`

Comment: all methods in java starts from lowercase.

Comment: @nishpystoned are you sure that you have written setLayout(new FlowLayout)?

Comment: @AJ.Nope when i used that it is giving me error saying:"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\java\bitmap\RandomImages.java:21: '(' or '[' expected
 setLayout(new FlowLayout);
                         ^"

Comment: @nishpystoned there is a mistake in my code,, use 'setLayout(new FlowLayout());'  sorry for that

Comment: @AJ.Well now there r no errors but its still the same blank view with no images..

Comment: @nishpystoned try to give the absolute path of image in new ImageIcon("Image.jpg")

Comment: @AJ. Well it is still the same blank!!

Answer (score 0):

1)Instead of using `paint(Graphics g)` for custom paintings you need to use [`paintComponent(Graphics arg0)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) of `JComponent`. For example draw image on `JPanel` and the add panel to your frame. Your `JFrame` isn't a `JComponent`.

2) As I know `public static void main(String[] args)` ;)

Read more about [customPaintings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).